# Access attribute of one class from another class in Python

Tags: python, oop

I' playing with OOP (OOP concept is something totally new for me) in Python 3 and trying to access attribute (list) of one class from another class. Obviously I am doing something wrong but don't understand what.

```
from urllib import request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class getUrl(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.appList = []
        self.page = None
    def getPage(self, url):
        url = request.urlopen(url)
        self.page = url.read()
        url.close()
    def parsePage(self):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(self.page)
        for link in soup.find_all("a"):
            self.appList.append(link.get('href'))
        return (self.appList)

class getApp(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def selectApp(self):
        for i in getUrl.appList():
            return print(i)

a = getUrl()
a.getPage("http://somepage/page")
a.parsePage()

b = getApp()
b.selectApp()
```

And I get:

```
AttributeError: type object 'getUrl' has no attribute 'appList'
```

Comment: It makes no sense for getApp to be a class here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems to confuse classes with functions. Normally a function name is a verb (e.g. `getUrl`) because it represents an action. A class name is usually a noun, because it represents a class of objects rather than actions. For example, the following is closer to how I would expect to see classes being used:

```
from urllib import request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class Webpage(object):
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.app_list = []
        url = request.urlopen(url)
        self.page = url.read()
    def parse(self):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(self.page)
        for link in soup.find_all("a"):
            self.app_list.append(link.get('href'))
        return self.app_list

class App(object):
    def __init__(self, webpage, number):
        self.webpage = webpage
        self.link = webpage.app_list[number]

my_webpage = Webpage("http://somepage/page")
my_webpage.parse()
selected_app = App(my_webpage, 1)
print (selected_app.link)
```

Note that we usually make an instance of a class (e.g. `my_webpage`) then access methods and properties of the instance rather than of the class itself. I don't know what you intend to do with the links found on the page, so it is not clear if these need their own class (`App`) or not.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass in the `getUrl()` *instance*; the attributes are not present on the class itself:

```
class getApp(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def selectApp(self, geturl_object):
        for i in geturl_object.appList:
            print(i)
```

(note the removed `return` as well; `print()` returns `None` and you'd exit the loop early).

and

```
b = getApp()
b.selectApp(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `appList` is a variable in an instance of the `getUrl` class. So you can only access it for each instance (object) of the `getUrl` class. The problem is here:

```
class getApp(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def selectApp(self):
        for i in getUrl.appList():
            return print(i)
```

Look at `getUrl.appList()`. Here you call the class, not an object. You might also want to look at the `return print(i)` statement.

Answer (score -1):

Use requests instead of urllib, it's more comfortable.