# Call attribute of a class into another one

Tags: python, class, properties, attributes

I have two classes: one with parameters of a configuration and another that represents a user.

```py
class Configuration():
    def__init__(self, Attribute1):
       self.Attribute1 = Attribute1
    
    @property
    def Attribute1(self): 
       return self_Attribute1
    @Attribute1.setter
    def Attribute1(self, value): 
       self._Attribute1 = value

###############################

class User(): 
    def __init__(self, UserAttribute):
        self.UserAttribute = UserAttribute
    
    @property
    def Calculation(self): 
        return self.UserAttribute * Configuration.Attribute1
```

Obviously the code above doesn't work because ok this error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'property'
```

That is cause because I'm trying to access to the attribute of Configuration class.
So, how can I access to that attribute in the User class?
Yes, I thought of inheritance, but that would mean I'd have to initialize every time the same attributes all over for every "user" class. That's not so handy...
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `Attribute1` is an instance attribute, there is no instance of `Configuration` anywhere.

Comment: There is in a linked file where I uses these classes. But I'd like to know if there is a "universal" way to just refer attributes of a class into another. Otherwise I'd have to create a function in the linked file where I do basically the calculus I'd do in the User class

Comment: That isn't making much sense. In any case, **you need an instance to use the instance attributes**. Otherwise, **don't make them instance attributes**. This is pretty fundamental. The *attributes don't belong to the class at all*. Again, this is very important to understand

Comment: Also, these `property`'s are pointless, you don't need them and shouldn't use them like this

Comment: Really, a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26687845/access-attribute-of-one-class-from-another-class-in-python and probably many other questions

Comment: I used properties because I needed setter and getters, is there another way to do it better? what should I Use?

Comment: Your getters and setters *dont' do anything in `Configuration`*. You *don't need them*. The one in `User` would be fine

Comment: In the example above they dont't but in my full code I need setter and getter. Basically I first create an object of class Configuration without knowing the value Attribute1. So I instantiate it as 0. Then when I have the said value available I use the setter...

Answer (score 1):

You should pass an instance of the `Configuration` class to your `User`:

```py
class User(): 
    def __init__(self, UserAttribute, configuration):
        self.UserAttribute = UserAttribute
        self.configuration = configuration
    
    @property
    def Calculation(self): 
        return self.UserAttribute * self.configuration.Attribute1

configuration = Configuration(1)
user = User(attribute, configuration)
```

Comment: I think that this would surely works, the problem is that in my real code I first create an user object. Then I create a Configuration object. So I'd have to pass first an empty configuration object to the user one, then update the one i passed to the user with the one I update later on. If only I could "make a reference" globally to the attribute of the configuration in the user class that would be perfect xD

Comment: Its perfectly possible to pass `None` for `configuration` (or revert back to your original code), but when you have the configuration available update the users: `user.configuration = configuration`. As a programmer you should try very, *very*, **very** hard not to use globals.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know you can pass none, that's very usefull! thanks! 
indeed I'm trying not tu use global variables. :) thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 1):

add this line of code after configuration class

```
config = Configuration()
```

then in user class
instead of return `self.UserAttribute * Configuration.Attribute1`
do return `self.UserAttribute * config.Attribute1`